# Should I create a header file for lex functions?

Tags: c, linker, lex

I have a lex input .l file that includes a bunch of rules and function definitions for when those rules are encountered.

I am using this scanner from another source file, main.c

In main.c, I can call yylex() without having to have any kind of reference to my generated lex file. Why does this work? I am using cmake, and I noticed that it creates an object out of my lexer.c file, and links that to my executable. I would have thought I would need an external reference to yylex() though for that to work.

My question is should I create forward declarations for all of the functions I use in my lex .l file in a separate header, and include that in the lex file? Taking it a step further, should I define those functions outside of the lex file, and have them be used by way of referencing the include file?

Comment: You should enable warnings and pay attention to any and all compiler messages. The compiler will tell you exactly which declarations are missing where. In general, any publicly accessible function that you define should be declared in some header, and this header should be included by any file which uses the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `yylex()` with no problem because it's an `int` function. So technically you don't need a prototype (although this is not proper C99 or C1x behavior).

It's **always** a good idea to have a header file for all of your external (public) types, variables, and functions. You are not *required* to include it in your lex source file, but it's a very good idea to do so (if nothing else, to check that your declarations are correct). You definitely *should* include the header it in any file that uses the lex functions.